# Script isn't working inside jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have this jQuery code:

```
document.getElementById('geo_us').innerHTML = "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.101greatgoals.com/wp-content/themes/tutorial/js/gadout.js'></scr" + "ipt>";
$("#geo_us").append("<div id='div-gpt-ad-1335877669074-0' style='width:160px; height:600px;'></div>");
document.getElementById('div-gpt-ad-1335877669074-0').innerHTML = "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.101greatgoals.com/wp-content/themes/tutorial/js/gad.js'></scr" + "ipt>";
```

This is the result I am getting: The content/code of the external js is not there..

```
<div id="geo_us">
   <script src="http://www.101greatgoals.com/wp-content/themes/tutorial/js/gadout.js" type="text/javascript">
   </script>
   <div style="width: 160px; height: 600px;" id="div-gpt-ad-1335877669074-0">
      <script src="http://www.101greatgoals.com/wp-content/themes/tutorial/js/gad.js" type="text/javascript">
      </script>
   </div>
</div>
```

Do you know what's wrong in the code?

Thanks.

Comment: @ZenLikeThat I don't know of any browsers in current use that don't support `getElementById` with the possible general exception of Blackberry and maybe Opera Mini.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Load a script or retrieve content?

Answer (score 2):

You can not add script tags with innerHTML, use append with document.create element. Why are you mixing jQuery and regular JavaScript. Pick one.

```
var str = '<script src="http://www.101greatgoals.com/wp-content/themes/tutorial/js/gadout.js"></script><div style="width: 160px; height: 600px;" id="div-gpt-ad-1335877669074-0"><script src="http://www.101greatgoals.com/wp-content/themes/tutorial/js/gad.js"></script></div>';
jQuery("#geo_us").append( str );
```

Comment: why was this downvoted :X scripts added with innerHTML do not execute

Comment: I think there is a way unless you are totally sure about it. I saw comment of people with suggestions solving it but didn't work for me.

Comment: @user1341839 simply use jQuery's `.html()`, it explicitly finds any script tags and executes them since `.innerHTML` doesn't do it.

Comment: Not working for me but I found another way of doing it:$('#geo_us').load('tag160X600left.php'); but it's working only in chrome and on others it says google is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#geo_us').html("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.101greatgoals.com/wp-content/themes/tutorial/js/gadout.js'></scr" + "ipt>");

$("#geo_us").append($("<div id='div-gpt-ad-1335877669074-0' style='width:160px; height:600px;'></div>"));

$('#div-gpt-ad-1335877669074-0').html("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.101greatgoals.com/wp-content/themes/tutorial/js/gad.js'></scr" + "ipt>");
```

Comment: Not working for me but I found another way of doing it:$('#geo_us').load('tag160X600left.php'); but it's working only in chrome and on others it says google is not defined.